# Pytorch profiler shows different average execution time for convolution for two different networks

Tags: pytorch, profiling

I have two networks and I'm profiling them to see which operations are taking most of the time. I noticed that the `CUDA time avg` for the `aten::conv2d` operation is different for different networks. That too by an order of magnitude. In my first network, it is `22us`, whereas for the second network it is `3ms`. My first network has convolution layers with up to `512` filters, but the second one has only up to `192` filters. So, I would expect that the average time taken by convolution operation should be lesser in my second network. Instead, it is 3 orders of magnitude higher. Why would this be happening?

The full profiling output is below

Network 1:

```
                                                  Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg     Self CUDA   Self CUDA %    CUDA total  CUDA time avg    # of Calls  

                                      cudaLaunchKernel        99.80%     933.739ms        99.80%     933.739ms      20.750ms       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            45  
                                       model_inference         0.05%     453.000us       100.00%     935.567ms     935.567ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us     195.000us             1  
                               aten::cudnn_convolution         0.04%     388.000us        99.84%     934.047ms     103.783ms     195.000us       100.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                    aten::_convolution         0.01%     138.000us        99.88%     934.419ms     103.824ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                          aten::conv2d         0.01%     122.000us        99.89%     934.592ms     103.844ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                            aten::add_         0.01%     112.000us         0.02%     155.000us      17.222us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                              aten::upsample_nearest2d         0.01%      82.000us         0.01%     105.000us      26.250us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                           aten::empty         0.01%      79.000us         0.01%      79.000us       3.292us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            24  
                                       aten::threshold         0.01%      74.000us         0.02%     149.000us      18.625us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             8  
                                            aten::_cat         0.01%      71.000us         0.01%     119.000us      29.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                            aten::relu         0.01%      57.000us         0.02%     206.000us      25.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             8  
                                     aten::convolution         0.01%      51.000us        99.88%     934.470ms     103.830ms       0.000us         0.00%     195.000us      21.667us             9  
                                            aten::view         0.01%      50.000us         0.01%      50.000us       5.556us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                                             aten::cat         0.00%      32.000us         0.02%     151.000us      37.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                         aten::reshape         0.00%      29.000us         0.01%      79.000us       8.778us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                                         aten::resize_         0.00%      25.000us         0.00%      25.000us       0.962us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            26  
                                            aten::rsub         0.00%      21.000us         0.00%      33.000us      33.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                             aten::mul         0.00%      17.000us         0.00%      27.000us      27.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                           aten::zeros         0.00%      13.000us         0.00%      16.000us      16.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                       cudaEventRecord         0.00%      12.000us         0.00%      12.000us       1.333us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             9  
                                       cudaBindTexture         0.00%      11.000us         0.00%      11.000us       2.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                   aten::empty_strided         0.00%       6.000us         0.00%       6.000us       6.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
                                           aten::zero_         0.00%       1.000us         0.00%       1.000us       1.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             1  
cudnn::maxwell::gemm::computeOffsetsKernel(cudnn::ma...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     195.000us       100.00%     195.000us     195.000us             1  
                                     cudaUnbindTexture         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
Self CPU time total: 935.583ms
Self CUDA time total: 195.000us
```

Network 2:

```
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg     Self CUDA   Self CUDA %    CUDA total  CUDA time avg    # of Calls  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                        cudaMemcpyAsync        42.86%        1.035s        42.86%        1.035s      11.495ms       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            90  
                                       cudaLaunchKernel        34.81%     840.325ms        34.81%     840.325ms     169.969us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us          4944  
                                  cudaStreamSynchronize        15.92%     384.331ms        15.92%     384.331ms       5.736ms       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            67  
                                        model_inference         1.51%      36.559ms       100.00%        2.414s        2.414s       0.000us         0.00%        1.215s        1.215s             1  
                                            aten::fill_         1.03%      24.843ms        34.91%     842.670ms       7.731ms       8.759ms         0.72%       8.759ms      80.358us           109  
                                              aten::sum         0.57%      13.648ms         0.91%      22.019ms      18.123us      57.415ms         4.73%      57.415ms      47.255us          1215  
                                            aten::slice         0.50%      12.124ms         0.59%      14.229ms       3.526us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us          4035  
                                              aten::mul         0.49%      11.935ms         0.88%      21.340ms      17.293us     492.228ms        40.52%     492.228ms     398.888us          1234  
                                            aten::empty         0.44%      10.568ms         0.44%      10.568ms       2.556us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us          4134  
                                            aten::clamp         0.31%       7.455ms         0.84%      20.342ms      19.485us      12.405ms         1.02%      24.810ms      23.764us          1044  
                                              aten::add         0.25%       6.053ms         0.36%       8.615ms      14.334us      33.147ms         2.73%      33.147ms      55.153us           601  
                                aten::cudnn_convolution         0.18%       4.459ms         0.27%       6.549ms      46.779us     423.769ms        34.88%     423.769ms       3.027ms           140  
                                              aten::div         0.16%       3.892ms         0.27%       6.584ms      16.098us       3.225ms         0.27%       3.225ms       7.885us           409  
                                          aten::resize_         0.09%       2.287ms         0.10%       2.445ms       2.582us      75.000us         0.01%      75.000us       0.079us           947  
                                            aten::copy_         0.09%       2.226ms        58.96%        1.423s       6.498ms      80.877ms         6.66%      81.024ms     369.973us           219  
                                             aten::_cat         0.09%       2.087ms         0.12%       2.971ms      34.547us      26.689ms         2.20%      26.689ms     310.337us            86  
                                       aten::as_strided         0.09%       2.082ms         0.10%       2.305ms       0.554us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us          4164  
                                  aten::constant_pad_nd         0.06%       1.497ms        34.09%     822.790ms       9.350ms       0.000us         0.00%      46.706ms     530.750us            88  
                                     aten::_convolution         0.05%       1.113ms         0.38%       9.142ms      65.300us       0.000us         0.00%     440.725ms       3.148ms           140  
                                              aten::sub         0.04%       1.082ms         0.08%       1.905ms      18.676us      16.975ms         1.40%      16.975ms     166.422us           102  
                                       aten::leaky_relu         0.03%     727.000us         0.05%       1.253ms      19.277us      11.039ms         0.91%      11.039ms     169.831us            65  
                                       aten::reciprocal         0.03%     722.000us         0.05%       1.258ms      17.971us      10.340ms         0.85%      10.340ms     147.714us            70  
                                            aten::index         0.03%     707.000us         0.09%       2.140ms      66.875us      16.861ms         1.39%      17.207ms     537.719us            32  
                                             aten::add_         0.03%     672.000us         0.04%       1.027ms      14.671us      16.956ms         1.40%      16.956ms     242.229us            70  
                                           aten::conv2d         0.03%     610.000us         0.43%      10.298ms      73.557us       0.000us         0.00%     440.725ms       3.148ms           140  
                                             aten::view         0.03%     605.000us         0.03%     619.000us       2.623us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us           236  
                                    aten::empty_strided         0.02%     564.000us         0.02%     564.000us       6.409us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            88  
                                      aten::convolution         0.02%     546.000us         0.40%       9.688ms      69.200us       0.000us         0.00%     440.725ms       3.148ms           140  
                                           aten::narrow         0.02%     534.000us         0.06%       1.388ms       4.131us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us           336  
                                              aten::cat         0.02%     511.000us         0.14%       3.482ms      40.488us       0.000us         0.00%      26.689ms     310.337us            86  
                                               aten::to         0.02%     413.000us        58.86%        1.421s       9.665ms       0.000us         0.00%      42.584ms     289.687us           147  
                                             aten::rsub         0.02%     374.000us         0.03%     616.000us      19.250us      92.000us         0.01%      92.000us       2.875us            32  
                                           aten::select         0.01%     311.000us         0.01%     354.000us       4.023us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            88  
                                          aten::reshape         0.01%     304.000us         0.03%     660.000us       3.976us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us           166  
                                             aten::ceil         0.01%     265.000us         0.03%     717.000us      21.088us     606.000us         0.05%       1.212ms      35.647us            34  
                                          aten::permute         0.01%     214.000us         0.01%     249.000us       4.446us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            56  
                              aten::upsample_bilinear2d         0.01%     199.000us         0.03%     629.000us      34.944us       2.185ms         0.18%       2.260ms     125.556us            18  
                                           aten::expand         0.01%     189.000us         0.01%     246.000us       3.417us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            72  
                                             aten::ones         0.01%     180.000us         1.02%      24.632ms     947.385us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            26  
                                               aten::gt         0.01%     162.000us         0.02%     474.000us      29.625us     496.000us         0.04%     992.000us      62.000us            16  
                                           aten::repeat         0.01%     154.000us         0.03%     724.000us      60.333us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            12  
                                        cudaEventRecord         0.01%     146.000us         0.01%     146.000us       1.043us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us           140  
                                        aten::unsqueeze         0.01%     144.000us         0.01%     177.000us       3.404us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            52  
                                       aten::contiguous         0.01%     139.000us         0.03%     735.000us      22.969us       0.000us         0.00%     346.000us      10.812us            32  
                                             aten::mean         0.01%     137.000us         0.01%     214.000us      23.778us     131.000us         0.01%     131.000us      14.556us             9  
                                           aten::arange         0.01%     124.000us         0.01%     242.000us      10.083us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            24  
                                       aten::empty_like         0.01%     123.000us         0.01%     284.000us       5.680us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            50  
                                        cudaBindTexture         0.01%     121.000us         0.01%     121.000us       3.025us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            40  
                                            aten::stack         0.00%     112.000us         0.03%     802.000us      50.125us       0.000us         0.00%     158.000us       9.875us            16  
                                            aten::floor         0.00%      77.000us         0.01%     191.000us      23.875us      18.000us         0.00%      36.000us       4.500us             8  
                                         aten::moveaxis         0.00%      73.000us         0.01%     276.000us      11.500us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            24  
                                          aten::movedim         0.00%      67.000us         0.01%     203.000us       8.458us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            24  
                                           aten::unfold         0.00%      61.000us         0.00%      82.000us       2.562us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            32  
                                      aten::leaky_relu_         0.00%      51.000us         0.00%     119.000us      23.800us       0.000us         0.00%     789.000us     157.800us             5  
                                         aten::_s_where         0.00%      51.000us         0.00%      91.000us      22.750us     536.000us         0.04%     536.000us     134.000us             4  
                                            aten::clone         0.00%      36.000us         0.01%     159.000us      31.800us       0.000us         0.00%     435.000us      87.000us             5  
                                            aten::where         0.00%      34.000us         0.01%     174.000us      43.500us       0.000us         0.00%     536.000us     134.000us             4  
                                        aten::expand_as         0.00%      27.000us         0.00%      70.000us       4.375us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            16  
                                            aten::zeros         0.00%      18.000us         0.00%      29.000us      14.500us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             2  
                                             aten::item         0.00%      16.000us         0.00%      22.000us       2.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             8  
                                          aten::detach_         0.00%      10.000us         0.00%      15.000us       3.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                            aten::alias         0.00%       8.000us         0.00%       8.000us       0.667us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            12  
                              aten::_local_scalar_dense         0.00%       6.000us         0.00%       6.000us       0.750us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             8  
                                                detach_         0.00%       5.000us         0.00%       5.000us       1.250us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             4  
                                            aten::zero_         0.00%       2.000us         0.00%       2.000us       1.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us             2  
                       Memcpy HtoD (Pageable -> Device)         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      41.981ms         3.46%      41.981ms     626.582us            67  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       8.759ms         0.72%       8.759ms     105.530us            83  
void at::native::unrolled_elementwise_kernel<at::nat...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      37.512ms         3.09%      37.512ms     451.952us            83  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      65.145ms         5.36%      65.145ms     208.131us           313  
void at::native::unrolled_elementwise_kernel<at::nat...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     416.783ms        34.31%     416.783ms     494.992us           842  
void at::native::reduce_kernel<256, 2, at::native::R...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       2.070ms         0.17%       2.070ms       8.519us           243  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      12.051ms         0.99%      12.051ms      24.950us           483  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       3.225ms         0.27%       3.225ms       7.885us           409  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      12.284ms         1.01%      12.284ms      24.277us           506  
void at::native::(anonymous namespace)::CatArrayBatc...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      26.580ms         2.19%      26.580ms     359.189us            74  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      11.039ms         0.91%      11.039ms     169.831us            65  
                         Memcpy DtoD (Device -> Device)         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     510.000us         0.04%     510.000us      22.174us            23  
cudnn::maxwell::gemm::computeOffsetsKernel(cudnn::ma...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      62.000us         0.01%      62.000us       5.167us            12  
                 maxwell_scudnn_128x32_relu_interior_nn         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       1.320ms         0.11%       1.320ms     132.000us            10  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      10.340ms         0.85%      10.340ms     147.714us            70  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      10.300ms         0.85%      10.300ms     130.380us            79  
void at::native::unrolled_elementwise_kernel<at::nat...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      50.898ms         4.19%      50.898ms     242.371us           210  
void cudnn::winograd::generateWinogradTilesKernel<0,...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       1.166ms         0.10%       1.166ms      13.250us            88  
maxwell_scudnn_winograd_128x128_ldg1_ldg4_tile148n_n...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     150.355ms        12.38%     150.355ms       1.709ms            88  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       3.775ms         0.31%       3.775ms      78.646us            48  
                maxwell_scudnn_128x128_relu_interior_nn         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     106.000us         0.01%     106.000us     106.000us             1  
                   maxwell_scudnn_128x128_relu_small_nn         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     104.000us         0.01%     104.000us     104.000us             1  
                                      cudaUnbindTexture         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us            40  
void cudnn::detail::implicit_convolve_sgemm<float, f...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      12.632ms         1.04%      12.632ms     789.500us            16  
void at::native::reduce_kernel<256, 2, at::native::R...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      10.000us         0.00%      10.000us      10.000us             1  
void at::native::(anonymous namespace)::upsample_bil...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us       2.185ms         0.18%       2.185ms     121.389us            18  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     606.000us         0.05%     606.000us      35.647us            17  
void at::native::reduce_kernel<128, 4, at::native::R...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     121.000us         0.01%     121.000us      15.125us             8  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      18.000us         0.00%      18.000us       4.500us             4  
void at::native::unrolled_elementwise_kernel<at::nat...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     103.000us         0.01%     103.000us      12.875us             8  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     121.000us         0.01%     121.000us       7.562us            16  
void at::native::(anonymous namespace)::CatArrayBatc...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     109.000us         0.01%     109.000us      13.625us             8  
void at::native::unrolled_elementwise_kernel<at::nat...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     354.000us         0.03%     354.000us      11.062us            32  
void at::native::vectorized_elementwise_kernel<4, at...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us      92.000us         0.01%      92.000us       2.875us            32  
void at::native::unrolled_elementwise_kernel<at::nat...         0.00%       0.000us         0.00%       0.000us       0.000us     346.000us         0.03%     346.000us      10.812us            32  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 2.414s
Self CUDA time total: 1.215s
```

Profiling code:

```
with torch.no_grad():
  with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU, ProfilerActivity.CUDA], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("model_inference"):
      output_batch = self.frame_predictor(input_batch)
  print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="self_cuda_time_total", row_limit=10))
```

Comment: can you show the network definition and how you profile them?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share the entire network definition at this point of time. Basically, the first network is a U-Net with 4 downsampling layers and the second is a modified version of PWC-Net available [here](https://github.com/lliuz/ARFlow/blob/master/models/pwclite.py#L108-L202). I've added the code on how I profiled it.

Comment: The speed of a convolution depends on the input size, kernel size, dilation, stride, padding, etc (the question only mentioned that the filter size is the same). There are also different convolutional "algorithms" in cudnn that works best for different input sizes/hardware.

Comment: On top of it, it seems that the phenomenon is inverted when looking at the avg CPU times.